# ZK : Combobox sort

Tags: sorting, combobox, zk

I am trying sort combobox like listheader does. Is there any metod for comobobox in zul  like sort(auto) ? I should sort texts in combobox A-Z.

Comment: You can sort the data before put them into model

Answer (score 1):

Simple Awnser: No.
If you need help by sorting please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ORDER BY when quering your list
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp